# dynamic three.js glsl shader texture best practice

Tags: three.js

I'd like to have a dynamic GLSL shader texture to be used as a reference map (for displacement and other stuff) on multiple, different materials on different Meshes.

My approach would be to do the computation one time, using a THREE.WebGLRenderTarget, setup a ortho cam, a 1X1 plane with a THREE.ShaderMaterial, and access the WebGLRenderTarget.texture, that I'd embed in a "master" object, whenever and wherever I need.

Is there any "official" object I can / may use for this? I seen the postprocessing objects are pretty similar (EG ShaderPass) but I'm unsure if and how to use them.

Thank you.

Comment: That sounds like a perfectly good way to do this, I wouldn't bother trying to reuse these few lines of code.. I did pretty much the exact same thing already: https://codepen.io/usefulthink/pen/ALEyNB

Comment: thanks for your point Martin